# Printing issue with X-axis motor

Tags: print-quality, stepper, motor, axis

Here's an idea of what's going on. This is a picture of the progress during the first layer:

[image: Picture of the progress during the first layer]

Printing a simple calibration square, and as you can see, my X-axis is not moving like it should. I turned my speeds down from 30 mm/s to 5 mm/s and this is the result.

**What happens:**

1. Printing starts after homing and proper temperatures have been reached.
2. Starting from lower left, printing starts, filament pushed out.
3. X-axis motor is told to move, but it doesn't. Takes 0.5 seconds to think about the given order and only then moves. By now, a smudge of filament has been pushed into a blob at the start corner but the move is executed at a proper speed. Reaches "destination" and stops moving. *This has resulted in too short of a face for X-axis.*
4. Y-axis receives the order to move and does so properly. Lower left corner is done properly due to Y axis moving instantly.
5. Y reaches it goal destination, X receives orders to go to left. Lags behind, filament pushed out creates a smudgy corner due to lag. Reaches "destination" (lag is the same so it creates a regular pattern)
6. Y receives orders to go back to start coordinates and does so.

And this can be seen on the diagonal lines. Y moves constantly, X lags behind so it creates those vertical lines.

No idea what's causing this and causing a bit of a headache.

Things I've tried:

- Slowing down
- Calibrations
- Adjusting belt tension
- Different COM port
- Printing from SD card
- Tightening the pulley teeth onto the stepper motor

Getting this far was already a pain and now I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: Is this a new printer to you, or have you had it working fine in the past?

Comment: If you try to move the head when the X-stepper is enabled, then the print head sits still?

Comment: @fred_dot_u It was working fine when I last used it but that was a long time ago.

Comment: @dotswe No. The head will move instantly as commanded. Which makes this really weird.

Comment: at first glance, your z-height is improper. The filament should be flatter, implying the bed should be higher or the nozzle lower, depending on the mechanical portion of the printer. Consider to re-calibrate (re-zero) and re-level the bed.

Comment: Is perhaps the nozzle loose?

Comment: @fred_dot_u That's just because I don't want to clog the nozzle due to the filament being pushed out when there's no movement by the X-axis.

Comment: @dotswe not sure what you mean by this, since my X is very visibly not moving when it clearly should be _during printing_.